# Constantly run a function in a form (C++)

Tags: c++, winforms

I am currently using two XBees, one of them attached to my computer, and the other on a homemade UAV. The Xbee on the plane is constantly sending data about about the plane, and I want to get that data using my C++ interface - a Form (I believe they're also called WinForms?). My form has a webBrowser in it that has Google Earth embedded, and I want to update the plane's location on the GE map. I know how to get the data from the XBee, but I just don't know how to get the code that gathers the data to execute constantly without input.

This project was someone else's who dropped it. I "inherited" this code, and it's a bit confusing to me due to lack of comments.

Comment: It's usual to thread off such data collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your message pump to use [`PeekMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644943.aspx) instead of the usual [`GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx).  This will allow you to process messages if any are available or do something else while the message loop is idle.

When using the Win32 API, it looks something like:

```
for (bool running = true; running; )
{
    // check for any window messages.  this operation does not block
    // if no messages are available.
    ::MSG message;
    const ::BOOL fetched = ::PeekMessage(&message, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
    if (fetched)
    {
        // process window message.
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);

        // need to check explicitly for WM_QUIT message, since the "false"
        // return value is already used to mean "there were no messages".
        running = (message.message != WM_QUIT);
    }
    else
    {
        // no messages available, thread is idle.  take time to check
        // auxiliary input source.  if no auxiliary input is available
        // and checking (and processing) the auxiliary inputs is very
        // fast, consider adding an extra ::Sleep() call to avoid hogging
        // up the CPU.
    }
}
```

For .NET based applications, you might want to take a look at the [`Application.Idle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.idle.aspx) event.